# Can cloud lifter work with 1/4 inch inputes

Tags: homerecording

I'm running a Behringer UM2, can I use cloud lifter to boost my dynamic mic going into the 1/4 inch input

Answer (score 2):

No.  The Cloudlifter is a preamp designed for low-output mics (typically ribbon mics).  It takes phantom power from the XLR mic input it's connected to.  Connect your microphone to the XLR socket on the Behringer UM2 that is designed to take it.